# Why does the state not change immediately after clicking, but only after reloading the page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list that displays data from an API. Each item has a Favorite button (heart icon) to add the item to your favorites. Adding to favorites works, everything is fine. But I ran into a problem. When I click on the Favorite button, a change occurs on my server, but visually nothing changes, the button does not change its state. I need to close the list page and reopen - then I will see the changes. Tell me, how can I make it so that after clicking on the button, it immediately changes its state and I do not have to reload the page?

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (widget.stationList != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < widget.stationList!.length; i++) {
        widget.stationList![i].isFavorite
            ? selected.add(true)
            : selected.add(false);
      }
    }
    return MediaQuery.removePadding(
      context: context,
      removeTop: true,
      child: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 44, top: 10, bottom: 10),
          child: Divider(
            height: 0.5,
            color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.20),
          ),
        ),
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: widget.stationList!.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CupertinoButton(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          onPressed: () {
          },
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      try {
                        log('this');
                        if (selected[index]) {
                          log('asdasdasdasdasdasd');
                          await FavoritesRepository()
                              .removeFavoriteStation(
                                stationId: widget.stationList![index].id,
                              )
                              .then((value) => (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selected[index] =
                                          !selected.elementAt(index);
                                    });
                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                      SnackBar(
                                        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                        elevation: 0,
                                        content: SystemMessagesSnackBar(
                                          message:
                                              'Successfully removed from favorites',
                                          textButton: null,
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                                .removeCurrentSnackBar();
                                          },
                                          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                              'assets/icons/approve_order.svg'),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  });
                        } else {
                          log('asdasdasdasdasdasd');
                          await FavoritesRepository()
                              .addFavoriteStation(
                                stationId: widget.stationList![index].id,
                              )
                              .then((value) => (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selected[index] =
                                          !selected.elementAt(index);
                                    });
                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                      SnackBar(
                                        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                        elevation: 0,
                                        content: SystemMessagesSnackBar(
                                          message:
                                              'Successfully added to favorites',
                                          textButton: null,
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                                .removeCurrentSnackBar();
                                          },
                                          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                            'assets/icons/approve_order.svg',
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  });
                        }
                      } catch (_) {
                        log(_.toString());
                      }
                    },
                    child: selected.elementAt(index)
                        ? const Icon(
                            Icons.favorite_rounded,
                          )
                        : const Icon(Icons.favorite_border_rounded),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        );
        } 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move these:

```
if (widget.stationList != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < widget.stationList!.length; i++) {
        widget.stationList![i].isFavorite
            ? selected.add(true)
            : selected.add(false);
      }
    }
```

to `initState`:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.stationList != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < widget.stationList!.length; i++) {
        widget.stationList![i].isFavorite
            ? selected.add(true)
            : selected.add(false);
      }
    }
  }
```

Every time you call setStat, because of in condition in going to regenerate initial data  in selected.